# Practicing Java, need help finding the output

Tags: java

I am looking to find the output of the following code.

Suppose that myStack is a linked implementation of a stack of Integers.
What would the output be for this code?

```
myStack.push(new Integer(1));
myStack.push(new Integer(2));
System.out.println(myStack.pop());
System.out.println(myStack.pop());
System.out.println(myStack.pop());
```

Comment: let run code ... what is a problem? "practicing" or "wanting to receive theoretical answer" ?

Comment: I am looking to find the output of the following code

Comment: What is the code **before** this code? And ***where*** did you look?

Comment: There isn't any code before this. I pulled this out of the textbook and there's no solution in the back and I want to learn what the output would be so I can understand how pops and push's work

Comment: If this is the only code than the stack gonna be underflow because only 2 elements are there and you are performing pop 3 times

Comment: @djsef Read the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) javadoc. In the Java implementation, if we did `Deque<Integer> myStack = new LinkedList<>();`, we would get 1 on the first, then 2 on the second and then `NoSuchElementException` on the third `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only code, then I believe it should throw a run time exception because you try to pop an element out of a stack when the stack size is zero.

So your output would be something like:

```
2
1
Error!!!!
```

Though that third line really depends on how your pop() method handles a stack with zero size.

Comment: After reading what Elliot recommended, do you think it would instead print out:
1
2
NoSuchElementException

Comment: It might. In the future it may be more efficient to write a tiny java program to find your answer. It'd be good java programming practice too.